# Communicate from Arudino to computer over 3.5mm port

Tags: softwareserial, communication, audio

I'm wondering if it would be somehow possibly to have easy communication with a computer for Arduinos that don't have USB like the pro mini. That would make an easy way of having two-way communication with a computer. The computer could just play or record audio using software written specifically for this purpose. Would something like this require any special circuitry or would it just be a matter of connecting the right wires?

Comment: This is exactly how old home computers loaded and saved data to cassette.

Comment: @Majenko I guess a good question would be, what standard was used, and if that standard maybe already has an Arduino implementation.

Comment: FSK is the most common and easiest to implement. You can transmit just with the `tone()` function if you time it right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the all page, but it seems it can be achieved, see [David Awehr's blog](https://davidawehr.com/blog/audioserial/) (this one is conected to a android phone instead to a PC tho) and this [Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/2014/11/04/using-a-headphone-jack-as-a-uart/) page where they seems to it, but the PC's audio input normally use 44,1kHz or 96kHz, so if you wanna go for the higher Serial speed (let's say just 115200bauds) you should think about it this.

Comment: Thanks, those articles will be a point to further my research.